# Pass event object to directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to pass the event object to a function in a directive

I have this in `question.page.html`

```html
<ion-content appHideHeader [header]="header" [scrollEvents]="true">
```

and I have this in `hide-header.directive.ts`

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHideHeader]'
})
export class HideHeaderDirective {
  @Input() header: HTMLElement;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('ionScroll')onContentScroll(e) {
    console.log('scroll');
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```

when I scroll, I get this in the console

```
scroll
undefined
```

I tried this and it did not work (which make sense)

```html
<ion-content appHideHeader [header]="header" [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onContentScroll($event)">
```

So, I would like to pass `$event` to `onContentScroll()` function in the directive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HostListener takes two argument first one is type of eventName,second one is array of values. you can pass $event like this

**Try this:**

```
@HostListener('ionScroll', ['$event'])onContentScroll(e) {
    console.log('scroll');
    console.log(e);
  }
```